# Is the underlying Sqlite file of CoreData portable across platforms?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, core-data-migration

When CoreData is saving its data in a Sqlite file, is that file portable e.g. from iOS to macOS? I ask because from a testing perspective this might be helpful. When I tried examining such a file a little while ago, its contents was sufficiently obfuscated that I couldn't tell.

Comment: Isn't each Sqlite file encrypted these days? In that case they shouldn't be portable. Also I have heard that they contain some info about the app they were created by.